# Iterate over files in a folder

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, tr

I have a folder containing files, and I need to iterate over them using unix command "tr" having as output the same name as before (if is possible) (the code below doesn't work):

```
FILES=/root/Desktop/prova/*
for f in $FILES ; do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    cat $f | tr "\n" "," > $f.tmp & mv $f.tmp $f 
done
```

I don't understand how can I use this command `cat "$f" | tr "\n" "," > "$f"` and redirect the output of each files. Then I should use another for loop to create N tool commands and run together. Have you any advice for loops studies?

Comment: use an intermediate file like `cat $f | tr "\n" "," > $f.tmp` and then `mv $f.tmp $f`

Comment: It works correctly, but only on the first item x00.txt. It doesn't iterate on x01.txt and x02.txt probably due to a wrong for loop.

Comment: `for f in /root/Desktop/prova/ ; do`

Comment: (1) You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$f"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  (2) With a few exceptions (like the `sponge` command mentioned by thrig), you can’t use the same file for input and output in the same command; see [this](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#186126).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cat` is a useless waste of CPU, eliminate it. Send the output instead to a temporary file, and rename that file back afterwards:

```
tr x y < input > input.tmp && mv input.tmp input
```

With `moreutils` installed, this may be done with `sponge` (which does the temporary file stuff behind the scenes):

```
tr x y < input | sponge input
```

Note that such renames may destroy fancy ACL or security contexts set on the now dearly unlinked original `input` file.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I will try to integrate it as soon as I will fix the loop.

Comment: as I said to @user236012; tr command works well for both solution, but only on the first file. Do u know why?

Comment: @heisen I have no idea what "works well but only the first file" means. The code you used, input supplied, and what results you saw vs. what you expected to see would be useful.

Comment: Now it works perfectly. It didn't worked before due to an problem in the above part of my script, but your solution is right. Thank you so much!